# admob interstitial fill rates

Tags: java, android, admob, interstitial

I have a problem with the interstitial fill rates. I know this questions is almost off topic, but as it has to have something to do with my code, I hope you guys won't close it and if someone has an idea, its highly appreciated.

For example in one app, i put this code in onCreate():

```
    private static InterstitialAd interstitialAd;

    ...

    interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    interstitialAd.setAdUnitId(ADMOBID_INTERSTITIAL);
    interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {

    ...

    AdRequest.Builder requestBuilder = new AdRequest.Builder();
    interstitialLoading = true;
    interstitialAd.loadAd(requestBuilder.build());
```

then the user has some input to do, which should take him at least 30-45 seconds. Then before the next activity is started, I do this:

```
 if (interstitialAd.isLoaded() && showAds) {
        interstitialAd.show();
 }
```

I mean there is no magic involved in this. I do not use any keywords for the requests. Normal ad banners are filled with 99%. My Interstitial only 30%-40%

Where can I improve this?

Comment: Did you check the logcat to see what's the response from Admob?

Comment: When I try it locally I almost always get an advert with my interstitial. Only the live ads seem to have this problems :/

Comment: I don't think there is a lot that can be done, though 30-40% in Admob is low. You might want to consider adding mediation.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the magic Admob! What does "normal"?

I think the problem is in your users. For example, they are from Africa... And there are few advertisers.

With such questions can honestly write to [the support admob](https://support.google.com/admob/contact/performance_issues?cfnti=title.performance.reporting&cft=3).

- [Learn this way](https://www.reddit.com/r/Unity3D/comments/3b1x9x/admob_interstial_low_fill_rate/).
- [SO no place for such questions](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Good luck!